# Find not working in script, working in terminal prompt

Tags: linux, bash, find, sh

I'm trying to run a bash script in linux (ubuntu but also fedora) but it the find command won't work.

```
search=\"*${exten[iterext]}\"
find $direc{iterdir} $r_option -iname $search exec -rm {} \\\;
```

Now to explain the variables:
Exten is array with file extensions read from a text file (no problem here)
direc is also an array of directories read from the command line.
Iterdir and iterext are cicle integer variables.

Now I have two problems:

1- This find command will not delete or display for that matter if I run it inside a script; however if I put an echo before the find and copy paste the output to a command prompt find works fine. I've tried the script under ubuntu and fedora so I assume it's not a bash configuration issue. I should note that the issue seems to the $search as I replaced $search with a hardcoded string (like "*txt) and it works inside the script so it's seems to be a quotation issue.

2 - I run that entire find command and also get find:missing argument to '-exec'

Please help :-( it's driving me insane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start simple by placing everything in the `find` command then worry about parameterizing it.

1. `${exten[iterext]}` should be `${exten[$iterext]}`
2. `$direc{iterdir}` should be `${direc[$iterdir]}`
3. `exec -rm` should be `-exec rm`
4. `\\\;` should be `\;`
5. Quote your variables to prevent word splitting

The following will perform a *dry run* thanks to the `echo`.  Simply remove the `echo` when you are satisfied with the output to perform the deletions.

```
find "${direc[$iterdir]}" "$r_option" -name "*${exten[$iterext]}" -exec echo rm {} \;
```

Comment: @PTGuy: NP, welcome to StackOverflow and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: Done :-) Quotes in bash can be a bit daunting.Yeah I didn't copy the code correctly (handwritten because I'm running inside a VM) But it was still wrong so... Thanks to both for the help

Comment: The dollar signs aren't necessary for array indices.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis, I once knew that fact but have since forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of quotes seems a little odd to me. Try this:

```
find "$direc{iterdir}" $r_option -iname "*${exten[iterext]}" -exec -rm "{}" ";"
```

Oh, and run your shell script with the `-x` option. This will print every command line before it is executed.

```
set -x
find "$direc{iterdir}" $r_option -iname "*${exten[iterext]}" -exec -rm "{}" ";"
set +x
```

Comment: There are many problems with his command more than just quotes, see the list in my answer.

Comment: Yes, after reading your answer, I noticed that. I didn't use the array variables up to now, so I didn't spot that error.